# Nodemailer not recognizing Core packages

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I am attempting to send emails suing the `nodemailer` module, and have run into an error when trying to build my application for development. I get the following error:

```
These dependencies were not found:
* child_process in ./node_modules/nodemailer/lib/sendmail-transport/index.js
* dgram in ./node_modules/native-dns-cache/lookup.js, ./node_modules/native-dns/lib/server.js
* fs in ./node_modules/native-dns/lib/platform.js, ./node_modules/nodemailer/lib/dkim/index.js and 2 others
To install them, you can run: npm install --save child_process dgram fs
```

I have tried to install them using the above command, but as they were core dependencies, I just got the security holder. I also have the modules in the actual Node.js folder, but nodemailer doesn't seem to recognize them.

How can I get nodemaier to recognize the modules used in the core installation?

EDIT:

By changing the paths in the nodemailer package, I was able to get a different set of errors looking for other files in the core program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was trying to use a Server-only package in Client mode.

https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/3271